# AMOS: Model is unidentified requires 26 additional constraints! How to fix?

Tags: modeling, structural-equation-modeling, amos

After running model on AMOS I am not getting any output path and this note appears in the text output: "The model is probably unidentified. In order to achieve identifiability, it will probably be necessary to impose 26 additional constraints."
I am attaching the model screenshot. This is my first attempt at the software I would appreciate some help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell with an amos diagram, but you have 26 variables, so I'm going to guess you haven't identified the means of the measured variables. (Or maybe the variances of the errors.)